# Show graph with differents parameters in a template - all graphs are mixed

Tags: jquery, d3.js, vuejs2

Top of the morning(or afternoon, or night...or whatever :D)

I'll try to be as clear as possible so do not hesitate to ask for precision if needed.

I have one page with a table and when you click on the one of the title (excluding sample id), it is suppose to show the corresponding histogram.
The histograms are each in a different hidden div calling for a template.

The issue is that when I call the first option, it returns all graphs in the same div.

You'll find my code and the issue -- here --> https://jsfiddle.net/Pawpaw/0tcga2zp/4/

```
<div id="app">
<table width="70%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>Sample id</th>
        <th onclick="showForm('gc_modal')">GC Dropout</th>
        <th onclick="showForm('at_modal')">AT Dropout</th>
        <th onclick="showForm('dup_modal')">% Duplicates</th>
        <th onclick="showForm('off_modal')">% Off target</th>
        <th onclick="showForm('trc_modal')">Total Read Count</th>
    </tr>   
</table>            
<div id='gc_modal' class="w3-modal">
<div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-top w3-card-4 form-modal">
  <header class="w3-container w3-theme-d1">
    <span onclick="$('#gc_modal').hide()"
      class="w3-button w3-display-topright w3-hover-red">&times;</span>
        <h3>GC Dropout</h3>
  </header> 
  <center><graph name='gc_dropout'></graph></center>
    <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">Tooltip</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id='at_modal' class="w3-modal">
<div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-top w3-card-4 form-modal">
  <header class="w3-container w3-theme-d1">
    <span onclick="$('#at_modal').hide()"
      class="w3-button w3-display-topright w3-hover-red"></span>
 <h3>AT Dropout</h3>
  </header> 
    <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">Tooltip</div>
    <graph name='at_dropout'>  </graph>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id='dup_modal' class="w3-modal">
 <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-top w3-card-4 form-modal">
  <header class="w3-container w3-theme-d1">
    <span onclick="$('#dup_modal').hide()"
      class="w3-button w3-display-topright w3-hover-red"></span>
        <h3>% Duplicates</h3>
  </header> 
    <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">Tooltip</div>
    <graph name='duplicates'>  </graph>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='off_modal' class="w3-modal">
  <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-top w3-card-4 form-modal">
  <header class="w3-container w3-theme-d1">
    <span onclick="$('#off_modal').hide()"
      class="w3-button w3-display-topright w3-hover-red"></span>
        <h3>% Off target</h3>
   </header> 
    <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">Tooltip</div>
    <graph name='off_target'>  </graph>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='trc_modal' class="w3-modal">
<div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-top w3-card-4 form-modal">
  <header class="w3-container w3-theme-d1">
    <span onclick="$('#trc_modal').hide()"
      class="w3-button w3-display-topright w3-hover-red">&times;</span>
        <h3>Total read count</h3>
  </header> 
    <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">Tooltip</div>
    <graph name='total_read_count'>  </graph>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- app closing div below-->
</div>
<!-- template where graph are drawn-->
<template id="graph-template">
    <svg id="container" height="600" width="1000"></svg>
</template>
```

I am trying to get the result of this one but without the calling methods ---there --> https://jsfiddle.net/Pawpaw/fkza1snd/

I keep reading vuejs documentation but I am starting to lose my mind and currently thinking of putting the Vue.components (methods) directly in the template and than trying to pass all datas from the components but I hope not to have to do this.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue isn't Vuejs related at all to be honest.

When using "d3.select('svg')" in row 112 in the first jsfiddle you've provided, you're selecting ANY svg in your whole dom. Since there are 5 present (one for each graph component) it will return the first svg element, which is the gc_dropout one.

When using those v-if statements, there's only one svg present, since vue.js doesn't add those elements to the Dom, when the if statement is false. So it works this way.

However the better way would be to use ids in that d3.select. Here is a simple fix for you

```
Line 73  <template id="graph-template"> 
Line 74     <svg :id="name + '_container'" height="600" width="1000"></svg>
Line 75  </template>

Line 112 var svg = d3.select('svg#'+param+'_container');
```

I've just added a prefix to the svg containers id, which equals the name prop.

I have to tell you, that the preferred way of creating such a view would be to stay with one library that manipulates the dom. otherwise they kind of "fight" each other. Vue for example uses this component architecture, but jQuery and that d3 thing don't care about those components.

One way to get a similar functionality with vuejs would be to use a ref on your svg. Here is a good tutorial for that by Bo Andersen https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/accessing-dom-refs